# Using Pybluez to connect to already paired bluetooth device?

Tags: python, bluetooth, pybluez

I am writing a python program that involves using a bluetooth device.Right now I'm able to connect to the bluetooth device from the python program but everytime I quit the python program I have to bring my device pack to pairing mode (by pulling a switch) and then pair with it again.
I was hoping if you could show any method through which I could connect automatically to the paired device , instead of bringing it to pairing mode and connecting again for each time I run the python program.

This is the code to my bluetooth python module :

```
import bluetooth
from bluetooth.btcommon import BluetoothError
import time

class DeviceConnector:

TARGET_NAME = "Device name"
TARGET_ADDRESS = None
SOCKET = None

def __init__(self):
    pass

def getConnectionInstance(self):
    self.deviceDiscovery()
    if(DeviceConnector.TARGET_ADDRESS is not None):
        print('Device found!')
        self.connect_bluetooth_addr()
        return DeviceConnector.SOCKET
    else:
        print('Could not find target bluetooth device nearby')

def deviceDiscovery(self):
    try:
        nearby_devices = bluetooth.discover_devices(lookup_names = True, duration=5)
        while nearby_devices.__len__() == 0 and tries < 3:
            nearby_devices = bluetooth.discover_devices(lookup_names = True, duration=5)
            tries += 1
            time.sleep (200.0 / 1000.0)
            print ('couldnt connect! trying again...')
        for bdaddr, name in nearby_devices:
            if bdaddr and name == DeviceConnector.TARGET_NAME:
                DeviceConnector.TARGET_ADDRESS = bdaddr
                DeviceConnector.TARGET_NAME = name
    except BluetoothError as e:
        print ('bluetooth is off')

def connect_bluetooth_addr(self):
    for i in range(1,5):
        time.sleep(1)
        sock = bluetooth.BluetoothSocket(bluetooth.RFCOMM)
        try:
            sock.connect((DeviceConnector.TARGET_ADDRESS, 1))
            sock.setblocking(False)
            DeviceConnector.SOCKET = sock
            return
        except BluetoothError as e:
            print('Could not connect to the device')
    return None
```

Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

**Hi, I'm not sure if this solves your problem , However this might point you in a right direction. Below is the code which will automatically connects to the target Bluetooth device as soon as the python program is executed. This is done by hardcoding the Bluetooth device's address**

```
import bluetooth


target_name = "enter your Bluetooth device name"
target_address = None

nearby_devices = bluetooth.discover_devices()

for bdaddr in nearby_devices:
    if target_name == bluetooth.lookup_name( bdaddr ):
        target_address = bdaddr
        break

if target_address is not None:
    print("found target bluetooth device with address ", target_address)
else:
    print("could not find target bluetooth device nearby")


bd_addr = target_address
print(bd_addr)

port = 1
sock = bluetooth.BluetoothSocket(bluetooth.RFCOMM)
```

Comment: This code does not connect to any device, it just prints if the configured device is available or not.